# Deploying to Heroku with 2 different languages, Python and NextJS, ignorant on how to configure to install dependencies for NextJS

Tags: python, heroku, next.js

I have a project I'm connecting from github to deploy to Heroku written in Python but a frontend directory that's written in NextJS. So my Root Directory is

```
Frontend/
Miscellaneous Python folder A/
Miscellaneous Python folder B/
Miscellaneous Python folder C/
...
Procfile
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
```

Procfile admittedly has nothing so I can omit that. Requirements has all my Python modules I used for the project and runtime.txt has a single line of the Python version I'm using.  Heroku doesn't innately have npm installed on the server so I can't launch my frontend otherwise. So the question I'm asking is which of these files do I configure for my frontend/ folder and how?

Answer (score 0):

I realized this was quite the multifaceted problem. But there are buildpacks you can install in the settings of Heroku. This way you can install node and get rid of that pesky "npm command not found". Of course, you'll want your package.json file in the root directory so heroku knows what modules to install (I haven't figured what to do if the rest of your project isn't in the root directory). Also in package.json, make sure your node version is included like so:

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "17.x"
  },
```

Also, you have to make sure your dev Dependencies are listed as opposed to Dependencies. I'll update as I figure out the last kink regarding my Nextjs project not in the root directory but this is the bulk of the hurdles that need to be cleared.